# Operate with dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary, which at the moment has 2 keys, but could have more (Each key will always have a single list with the amount of values they are).

I need to do the following operation:

If in the first key I have 2 values in my list, and in the second key I have a value in my list, then I am looking to multiply those values, example:

```
dict_v = {1: ['12X58', '14X53'], 2: ['10X60']}

total = 2 * 1 = 2
```

If I had a 3 key dictionary:

```
dict_v = {1: ['12X58', '14X53'], 2: ['10X60'], 3: ['8X58', '8X67', '10X49', '10X54']}

total = 2 * 1 * 4 = 8
```

I would greatly appreciate the help provided, kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the reduce function to calculate the multiplication of the len of the dictionary values.

```
dict_v = {1: ['12X58', '14X53'], 2: ['10X60'], 3: ['8X58', '8X67', '10X49', '10X54']}
total = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, map(len, dict_v.values()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
import math 

dict_v = {1: ['12X58', '14X53'], 2: ['10X60'], 3: ['8X58', '8X67', '10X49', '10X54']}

print(math.prod([len(v) for v in dict_v.values()]))
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried with numpy bookstore, you gave me a great idea, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools%20reduce#functools.reduce) to multiply the lengths of all the list values (obtained by mapping `len` to each value):

```
from functools import reduce

dict_v = {1: ['12X58', '14X53'], 2: ['10X60']}

print(reduce(lambda c, v: c * v, map(len, dict_v.values())))

dict_v = {1: ['12X58', '14X53'], 2: ['10X60'], 3: ['8X58', '8X67', '10X49', '10X54']}

print(reduce(lambda c, v: c * v, map(len, dict_v.values())))
```

Output

```
2
8
```

Answer (score 1):

This one may not be so Pythonic but it illustrates the steps well

```
# Set the initial value of your variable to 1 (as you will do multiplication with it)
total = 1

# With the following line you will create a list of all the values in your dictionary (each value is a list)
# Then multiply the current value of your "total" variable with the LENGTH of each list

for value in dict_v.values():
    total *= len(value)

print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `map()`,the faster way could be:

```
from functools import reduce

dict_v = {1: ['12X58', '14X53'], 2: ['10X60']}
print(reduce(lambda x, y: len(x) * len(y), dict_v.values()))
```

`map` will cost extra overhead.

---

By Test(`timeit.timeit:number = 100`):

```
# print(reduce(lambda x, y: len(x) * len(y), dict_v.values()))
4.309999999996261e-05

# print(reduce(lambda c, v: c * v, map(len, dict_v.values())))
5.319999999997549e-05
```

Not sure `math.prod`.I couldn't run it.